# What is the difference between forecasting based on ARIMA and logistic curve? R

Tags: r, time-series, logistic, forecasting, arima

I'm making a project connected with identifying the dynamics of sales. My database concerns 26 weeks (so equally in 26 time-series observations) after launching the product.

This is what my database looks like: https://imageshack.com/i/0yyh6ij

I want to make forecast based on S-curve for clusters of time-series. The main aim was to compare two methods of forecasting:

1. based on parameters of logistic curve
2. based on ARIMA

However, I do not know how to compare these two methods = measure their performance.

That's a plot with prediction based on S-curve

http://imageshack.com/a/img850/6600/rzkp.jpg

So my questions are:

1. How to measure performance=forecast errors based on logistic curve?
2. How to compare forecasting based on logistic curve and ARIMA - what is the main difference between these two approaches if I base on one variable - units_sold_that_week?

I would be grateful for any explanation.

Comment: That fit looks terrible; it's always below the data - how did you get that fit?? Looking at your data, it doesn't look S-shaped. That first series initially increases then decreases. If your data contains such a trend, neither model is necessarily particularly useful.

Comment: I updated the prediction image by changing my S-curve. How does it look now?

Comment: Well, it's better; but it still can't match the initial increase, and the existence of that part makes the rate of decrease too slow for the later part.